# height 100% with flex-wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I made layout with Flexbox.

When I use `flex-wrap: wrap`, other elements doesn't cover full height.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: azure;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="modal">Modal</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
</div>
```

I expect that .modal cover 100% height but it doesn't.

[image]

How can I made 100% height to .modal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the `. wrap` class:

Comment: Awesome! It's a good idea to put position relative on the parent regardless, or else your modal will be positioned relative to the body tag, which isn't usually what you want. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I will check it. Thanks for reply!